# C++ read text file until specific delimiter

Tags: c++, delimiter, readfile

Okay, so i have a huge file which i want to read in 1 Chapter at a time.
a chapter is delimited by `'$'`.
I am not really familiar with C++ just yet, so i made something that would read in a chapter as i would expect it to in C/C++.

```
#include <nds.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

int dataFileLoc = 7;

std::string fileReader(){
    FILE * dataFile;
    std::string chapterBuffer = "";
    const int buffersize = 1024;
    char charBuffer[buffersize];
    bool foundEnd = false;
    dataFile = fopen("xc3_.tsc", "rt");//open data file
    fseek(dataFile,dataFileLoc,SEEK_SET);
    while(!foundEnd){
        fread(charBuffer,1,buffersize,dataFile);
        for(int i=1; i<buffersize; i++){
            if(charBuffer[i] == '$'){
                foundEnd = true;
                charBuffer[i] = '\0';
                dataFileLoc = ftell(dataFile)-(buffersize-i);
                break;//break to spare some time
            }
        }
        chapterBuffer.append(charBuffer);
    }
    fclose(dataFile);//done with the file for now.

    checkerTemp(chapterBuffer);

    return chapterBuffer;
}
```

The result should be fine. I have never reached end of file yet. so it might fail there.
However, it seems to seemingly random (consistent, but at seemingly random locations). 
The fail would result in an injection of junk data in the string (like 8 chars worth), followed by normal data again.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this, or does anyone have a proper more C++ way to do this? Something with a string reader?

Thanks in advance,

-Smileynator

Comment: Check out [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). And of course you should learn more about the C++ [input/output facilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io).

Comment: Use `getline(file, data, '$')`, replace twenty lines of code with one.

Comment: The first character in the buffer is not being scanned. Use `for (int i =0; ...`

Comment: getline is something i will test to replace after this all works, for learning purposes :)

As for the `(int i=1;...` this is on purpose. the first character is ALWAYS the '$' because it indicates the start of a chapter. I skip it on purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One error is that if your while loop, loops around, then the statement

```
chapterBuffer.append(charBuffer);
```

is going to attempt to append a NOT terminated character buffer into the chapterBuffer - NOT a good thing. You will have to maintain within the for loop whether or not you found the '$'; if you did not then you will have to terminate the charBuffer; Or you can allocate buffersize + 1 bytes for charBuffer and set the charBuffer[buffersize] = '\0' before the loop;

Comment: This seems like a very logic answer, i am going to test it out when i get home! I was looking for something like this but i didn't find it on my own!

Answer (score 4):

You're using the C file API, you should be using the C++ iostream API.

To read in a chapter you should use `std::getline` with `'$'` as the delimiter argument. This means you don't need to worry about buffer allocation as the string object automatically allocates it.

The loop also becomes very simple.

```
while(std::getline(strm, str, '$').good())
    do_something_with_chapter(str);
```